# unable to open uiautomatorviewer on mac

Tags: android, eclipse, appium, uiautomatorviewer

i am getting below error while trying to open uiautomatorviewer from both terminal and try to open file itself.

MacBook-Pro:~ aalpesh81$ uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/aalpesh81/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/aalpesh81/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Support for java.ext.dirs was removed in Java 9, you will need to use Java 8 to run that.

Comment: I am using java 8 and still having same issue

Comment: On my mac I do not have Library/Android directory... where is the sdk tools installed for Studio?

Answer (score 0):

`uiautomatorviewer` only compatible with java 8. But there is another problem with mac. Even if you will be able to open the uiautomatorviewer, it won't work.Below screenshot for reference.

[UI automator and running in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cf2E.jpg)

However you can switch of appium inspector